# .NET, C#, reflection GetMethod return null (trying to get Methods inside third party dll)

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am trying to create an instance and call a method inside the DLL, but for some reason `GetMethod` returns `null`. Can anyone please advise what is wrong here?

```cs
//this works fine
Type myDllType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Application.name");

//this works fine too
object dllInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myDllType);

//this returns null,  I am 100% sure "methodmd" exists
MethodInfo methodCommand = myDllType.GetMethod("methodmd");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invoking GetMethod() on a System.\_\_ComObject always returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709626/invoking-getmethod-on-a-system-comobject-always-returns-null)

Comment: If it doesn't work as the link above suggests, then I would use JustDecompile to export the code into a project and just use it as normal code instead of the Dll.

Comment: It is third party dll and I do not have access to its code

Comment: your method "methodmd" must  be  public .

Comment: The string in Type.GetMethod(string) is case sensitive; it’s worth double-checking that “methodmd” is the correct case, and it’s not “MethodMd” or something else.  I know you say you’re 100% sure it’s named “methodmd”, but that’s an unusual string casing for a method name.

Comment: The method name is in correct case

Comment: @hagu How is method `methodmd` declared? What access modifiers are used (`private` / `public` / `internal`)? Is it a `static` or instance method?

Comment: It’s a public method